# Relation of two functions defined via real-valued Möbius transfrom

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Consider $u(x) := \frac{(a x + b)}{(c x + d)}$ where $a,b,c,d > 0$ and we take $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Let $v(x) := u(\frac{1}{x})$.

Consider the two functions
$$
F(x,y) := \frac{1+u(x)}{1+v(y)},\quad G(x,y) = \frac{1+[u(x)]^{-1}}{1+[v(y)]^{-1}}.
$$

We want to study the behavior of $F$ and $G$ together. Are there nice identities relating the two? Assume that $u(\infty) > 1$ and $v(\infty) < 1$. What can be said about the region where $F > 1$ and $G < 1$? Other information about the joint behaviour of these two functions is also appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever seen that the Möbius transformations can be identified with $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, where

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d} \sim \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right] ? $$

Comment: Yes, I have. So, ... ( Actually, I should say that I remember this vaguely, and I don't know what $PGL(2,C)$ is. Maybe I should say I haven't.)

Comment: Could you suggest a short introduction?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be useful for what I want.